# Data type unknown in case expression with only parameters as values

Tags: python, firebird

I'm getting this error message in Python, when I try to execute a trivial query. And if I change this query a little bit, then its ok. So, this is how it looks like:

```
>>> import fdb
>>> cnx = fdb.connect(dsn = "C:\data\REESTR.FDB", user = "sysdba", password = "masterkey")
>>> cnx.begin()
>>> cursor = cnx.cursor()
>>> query = "SELECT CASE WHEN 'val_1' = 'val_1' THEN ? ELSE 'val_2' END AS TXT FROM TEST_TABLE"
>>> dat = ('val_1', )
>>> cursor.execute(query, dat) # this query works ok
<fdb.fbcore.Cursor object at 0x0000000002FEC978>
>>> # now let's change the query a liitle bit:
>>> query = "SELECT CASE WHEN 'val_1' = 'val_1' THEN ? ELSE ? END AS TXT FROM TEST_TABLE"
>>> dat = ('val_1', 'val_2', )
>>> cursor.execute(query, dat)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\fdb-1.6-py3.4.egg\fdb\fbcore.py", line 3573, in execute
  self._ps = PreparedStatement(operation, self, True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\fdb-1.6-py3.4.egg\fdb\fbcore.py", line 2182, in __init__
  "Error while preparing SQL statement:")
  fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -804\n- 
  Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -804\n- 
  Data type unknown', -804, 335544569)
```

So, as you can see, I only added one additional prepared variable for `ELSE` part of the query. It all looks very strange because preparation for `THEN` part works good. You may not ask me about the schema of the table, since I do not use any field in this query. So, you can reproduce this error with any table.

**PROOF**

[image]

Comment: A tip: if you don't want to post the DDL of a table, don't post things like _"You may not ask me about the schema of the table, since I do not use any field in this query. So, you can reproduce this error with any table."_ It sounds abrasive and may make people less inclined to help. In this case you could also have used `RDB$DATABASE` instead to circumvent that, in other cases just post a minimal required DDL if the table is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Firebird needs to know the datatypes of the parameters (and of the resulting expression). It has several strategies to do that, so with

```sql
CASE WHEN 'val_1' = 'val_1' THEN ? ELSE 'val_2' END
```

It infers the type of the CASE expression based on the `ELSE 'val_2'` as a `CHAR(4)`, therefor the parameter in `THEN ?` is also a `CHAR(4)`.

However when presented with

```sql
CASE WHEN 'val_1' = 'val_1' THEN ? ELSE ? END
```

It has no information to infer the type of the parameters or of the `CASE` expression as a whole. For example, if this were a `WHERE` clause it could infer it based on the column the expression is compared to.

To help Firebird, you need to give a hint by casting one (or both) of the parameters explicitly to the right type (this works in Firebird 2.5 and later):

```sql
CASE WHEN 'val_1' = 'val_1' THEN CAST(? AS CHAR(4)) ELSE ? END
```

I believe (but didn't test) that in older Firebird versions you might be able to use something like

```sql
CASE WHEN 'x' <> 'x' THEN 'DUMMY' WHEN 'val_1' = 'val_1' THEN ? ELSE ? END
```

to make it a `CHAR(5)`.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! Your answer explains everything! But what if my variables are dynamic and I do not know in advance the exact length of a string parameter, so that at one moment it can be 'val_1' and at another moment it can be 'blablabla'? What is the right way to CAST it?

Comment: @Jacobian Unfortunately that is one of the limitations of Firebird, the size needs to be known at statement prepare time: you'll need to cast it big enough for all expected values (that also applies for `CASE WHEN 'val_1' = 'val_1' THEN ? ELSE 'val_2' END`, otherwise you limit that to `CHAR(4)`).

Comment: Oh, I see. I find it really incovenient. The query under discussion and prepared statement for this query works good in MySQL, SQlite, MSSQL, Oracle and Postgres. But from time to time I see some little nasty things that differ one database from another - like the lack of TOP or LIMIT in Oracle 11 and etc. And now I see such nasty thing in Firebird.

Comment: @Jacobian Yes, other database systems allow the driver to specify (or override) the type used on execute (or maybe they apply a default type, not sure about that); in Firebird that is only possible with a lot of limitations (for one the server really needs to know a type, that is doubly true here as it is also necessary to determine the type of the result column).